# Web audio only works with URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working on a project, and I can't seem to use web audio unless I'm uploading a file to the audio. These both work if I disable the mediaElement source stuff.
Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<input type="file" id="thefile" accept="audio/*" multiple/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
<audio id="audio">
<source src = "https://github.com/JuniperMakesStuff/JUNIVERSEGAME/blob/master/Nightcore%20-%20Rasputin%20(Remix)%20%E2%9C%95.mp3?raw=true" type = "audio/*">
</audio>
</div>
```

And then I've tried two sets of JS, here they are...

This one works, but when I upload the file, it will play it (I want to play a different file)

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event){
 mx = event.clientX
 my = event.clientY
})
var mx = 0
var my = 0

var all=0;
var shuffle=0;
var shuffleglide = 0;
var holdtime1 = 0;
var files = this.files
var selected = 0;
var previousall = 0;
var avg = 0;
var time = 0;
window.onload = function() {

var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
var audio = new Audio("https://github.com/JuniperMakesStuff/JUNIVERSEGAME/blob/master/Nightcore%20-%20Rasputin%20(Remix)%20%E2%9C%95.mp3?raw=true","mp3")

file.onchange = function() {
files = this.files;
selected = 0;
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0])
audio.load();
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
audio.loop = false;
var context = new AudioContext();
console.log(context)
var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

src.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

analyser.fftSize = 2048;

}
}
```

And this one straight up doesn't play any audio, even though i told it to play a different URL

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event){
mx = event.clientX
my = event.clientY
})
var mx = 0
var my = 0

var all=0;
var shuffle=0;
var shuffleglide = 0;
var holdtime1 = 0;
var files = this.files
var selected = 0;
var previousall = 0;
var avg = 0;
var time = 0;
window.onload = function() {

var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
var audio = new Audio("https://github.com/JuniperMakesStuff/JUNIVERSEGAME/blob/master/Nightcore%20-%20Rasputin%20(Remix)%20%E2%9C%95.mp3?raw=true","mp3")

file.onchange = function() {
files = this.files;
selected = 0;
audio.src = new URL("https://github.com/JuniperMakesStuff/JUNIVERSEGAME/blob/master/Blip_Select3.wav?raw=true");
audio.load();
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
audio.loop = false;
var context = new AudioContext();
console.log(context)
var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

src.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

analyser.fftSize = 2048;

}
}
```

I'm really sorry my code is so sloppy.

Comment: What is the state of the audio-context during all of this? (for example, keep checking `context.state` using `requestAnimationFrame`). I assume it will be `suspended` all the time, since you cannot start playing audio without a user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The `<audio>` element, and the JS `Audio` Object are not the same thing, though under the covers they implement the same thing. Ultimately you are creating an `Audio` object and trying to populate it's audio buffer with a remote file. It is important to remember a few things when you do this, a) the buffer has to be downloaded to the browser, and usually parsed, and b) this isn't an immediate process, as you do have to wait for the file to fully come to the browser.

It is possible to pre-load your remote sources to buffers that you cache in the browser and then swap out your buffer on-demand, it just takes a little work. In the end you must a) download your audio source, b) decode that source to an audioContext buffer, and c) apply that to your audio's `destination`. It's rather involved, and takes a bit of research to figure out all of the ins and outs. You can find a basic one off example of this in the [BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) documentation on MDN. You can also find an example in the [SoundTouchJS](https://github.com/cutterbl/soundtouchjs) library repository.